# Ubuntu 18.04 will only boot in recovery mode on HP Proliant dl380 G5

Tags: boot, drivers, server, hp

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 successfully on an HP Proliant dl380 G5 server, and after install, I was able to log into the system normally. However, once I reboot, after BIOS, I get a black screen with a monitor error message saying "Input signal out of range; Change settings to 1024 x 768".

After this, all I can do is to reboot. Once I reboot, I am able to hold down the shift key and Grub starts. Once in Grub I can select recovery mode and then resume normal boot, which boots into the command line.
I am assuming this is an issue with the graphics card, which is an ATI ES1000. 
I have run ubuntu-drivers-common.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have discovered the fix to my particular issue. I followed the instructions on this page https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm

This installs the Radeon Open Compute Platform, which from what I understand allows AMD GPUs to operate on a Linux system.